# Simple explanation for MVC (model view controller) pattern

Tags: model-view-controller

How would I go about explaining the model view controller (MVC) pattern to someone who has no programming experience whatsoever?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I were explaining this to my grandmother who is not a programmer, I'd explain it with *sugar*, a *cup of coffee*, and *herself*:

[image]

(Disclaimer:This is not an actual photograph of my grandmother! I am *not* a perfect painter with Microsoft Paint!)

Comment: Grandma will end up thinking you're a barista.  Especially if you write Java.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this person knows what a computer is and how to use a browser, I'd try something like this:

MVC stands for `Model`, `View` and `Controller`. Each of these have a role in a system.

- The `Model` **gets requests** from the `Controller` and sends back **data**.
- The `View` gets data from the `Controller` and **handles rendering**.
- The `Controller` has a larger role:

  - It **sends requests** to the `Model`, gets data back and passes on appropriate data to the `View`.
  - It gets and interprets requests from outside the MVC-pattern (client requests).

Otherwise, try an illustrative real life example:

- Your `Model` is a warehouse manager.
- Your `View` is a salesman.
- Your `Controller` is a general manager.

And the entire MVC-solution is the company they work in.

If you understand the MVC pattern yourself, I'm sure you can make make an understandable explanation from this.